# how to connect existing android app from github to bluemix

Tags: git, github, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, android-studio-2.3

I'm facing trouble connecting my android app from github to bluemix. Seems like there are tools to connect a web application to bluemix through github. Is there such thing for android apps or mobile apps in General

Comment: Try DevOps in Bluemix. You can bring the code from Github to Jazzhub https://hub.jazz.net and then work on it in Bluemix

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an easy way to get started with connecting your mobile app to Bluemix is choosing a [starter here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/mobile/create-project/), adding capabilities, and downloading the code.

Using the code, you can easily copy and paste over the relevant snippets and dependencies into your gradle for the features you want.

You may also choose to [read the documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/mobile/index.html#mobile) for how to add each service individually to your application.

Bluemix offers three core mobile services to attach to your app:

1. Mobile Analytics (for gathering analytics)
2. App ID (for authentication)
3. Push Notifications (for sending push notifications to mobile devices)

In addition, you may choose to extend your mobile app to use Watson or any of the Data services Bluemix has available.

---

If your question is about DevOps, you can connect your GitHub repository to Bluemix by [using the service here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/devops/getting-started).

Comment: Hi @pratiksaxena, did this answer your question?